# Font rendering bug on Vista

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

Good day.
I have strange bug with font rendering on Vista (WPF4).

Here is screenshot of my app on Win7

[image: win7]

And here is on Vista

[image: vista]

XAML code is very simple:

```
<Window ...
<Grid ...
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="32">This is some text</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24">This is some text</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="18">This is some text</TextBlock>
   <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14">This is some text</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I also tryed to switch different color schemes in OS options, but no luck :(

If I will resize the window, I may have:
[image]

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Is this a problem with only Verdana?

Comment: Probably with all. I tryed Vedana, Arial, Tahoma, Times and Trebuchet.

Comment: This is environmental.  Update the video driver, update DirectX next.

Comment: @rapt0r did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, after driver update everything is ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are both OSes in the same language, and are the regional settings the same? It may be that Verdana isn't installed correctly on your Vista.

Comment: Both OSes in English and System locale is set to English (United States)

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with DirectX and the way WPF renders texts using the graphics card. Have you tested with another Vista machine that has another gfx chipset?

Comment: Yes, mostly it works fine on all OS, but there are several computers with such bug.